# Redirecting to page based on today's date isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I'm not very familiar with scripts, etc... and I have a very precise question.
On one of my pages I want to redirect to a page, based on today's date.
Searching the web, I've come up with something like this at the moment :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>  
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();
    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
    var newurl = '/Documenten/Kalender_Datum_' + [year, month, day].join('-') + '.html';
//  document.location.href = redirect_datum;       
    alert(newurl);   // simulated redirection for testing purposes  only
}
</script>
</body>
```

But when I want to visit the page, it doesn't do much....
Can anyone explain me what's happening ? Are there any syntax-errors, or other ....
File can be found [HERE](http://kbkb.be/matchen_vandaag.html)
THX a lot
Carl

Comment: when user disable javascript option in brower, this approach will not work.you have to do this by server side scripting :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line of code

```
var d = new Date(date)
```

*date* is an undefined variable. It should be

```
var d = new Date()
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `date` argument passed to the `Date()` and wich is defined nowhere, and the script will work fine. This variable is not defined and cause an error, the script will not continue.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var d = new Date(),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();
  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
  var newurl = '/Documenten/Kalender_Datum_' + [year, month, day].join('-') + '.html';
  //  document.location.href = redirect_datum;       
  alert(newurl); // simulated redirection for testing purposes  only
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>
```

Comment: THX ! Removing the "date" argument really helped.